# genymotion allow su access permanently

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

1. In the Genymotion Configuration, I always have to check the box on "Always allow su access (bypass Superuser app)" then hit "Save" button.
2. It will then ask "Do you want to reboot?". I hit "Yes"
3. Rebooting. Sometimes it reboots successfully, sometimes it doesn't. Argh.

How do I make it permanent? Is there a file that genymotion uses so I can just edit it directly? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Genymotion parameters are kept using VirtualBox guest properties.
To list the current guest properties of a Genymotion VM, you should issue the command `VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate [Name of your VM]`

The parameter for "Always allow su access" is su_bypass
To set this parameter you should issue `VBoxManage guestproperty set [Name of your VM] su_bypass 1`

You can/should issue these commands while the VM is stopped.

Comment: Thanks @madCdan! I also tried setting the virtual keyboard using the property "vkeyboard_mode". Just curious how you learned the "su_bypass" property from?

Comment: "VBoxManage list vms" will show the names of the virtual machines
Thanks madCdan :)